# DBF File with unreadable fields. Are they encrypted, encoded weird, or something else?

Tags: database, encryption, encoding, visual-foxpro, dbf

I have a program that installs an updated database monthly into a special software we use. I get an .exe, run it, the .exe "installs" a bunch of DBF/CDX files into a folder, and then "hooks up" the database info into our software somehow.

Here is what the "installation" output folder looks like every month:

[image: Here is what the output folder looks like every month:]

I've opened the DBF I'm most interested pulling info from (parts.dbf) (with at least 4 different pieces of software I believe) and browsed the data. Most of the fields look fine, readable, all is good. However, the 2 fields that I NEED (Prices and Part Numbers) are unreadable. In the Parts column all of the fields show 10 or 12 characters followed by a bunch of 9's (examples:<\MFMIFJHMFll999999999999999999, KI9e^Z]pbk^999999999999999999,  JIFIPKMFL999999999999999999999). In the Price column its similar, just not as many characters (examples: LJKLGIQ999, IGII999999, JMQJGLL999).

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing exactly:

[image: Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing exactly:]

I have googled just about everything I know to google. I've downloaded different programs, tried to pull the data into Crystal Reports, tried to encode it differently (not sure I did that right, though), tried to figure out how to decrypt it (that journey was short-lived because it was so over my head), and just generally been pulling my hair out over this for weeks. I don't know what to do because I don't even really know where to begin. I'm just stabbing in the dark.

I *THINK* this file was created in some version of FoxPro but I could be wrong. When I view the information in our software it all shows up fine. Part Numbers and Prices look like readable human characters.

Example of data in our software:

[image: Example of data in our software:]

I'm out of ideas. I need to know what I'm working with so I can work on figuring out how to "fix it". Is this a FoxPro file? Is it encoded in a way that I need to change? Is it encrypted data in those two fields? Am I way off on everything?

Ideally, I'd love to pull this data into Crystal Reports and do my reporting thing with the data. Even Excel could probably work okay. As it stands though I can't do much reporting with a bunch of weird characters and 9's.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of Schema, per comment section:

[image]

Comment: This "DBF Commander" you're using...was it made for Foxpro DBF's? Cause there are a couple of different flavors of DBFs out there. (I think dbase used that extension too?) And Excel, last i tried it (20 years ago), could read one but not the other, so there are apparently differences.

Comment: @cHao

I believe so? I also have DBF Manager, DBF View, dBase (Trial), and opened the dbf in Open Office, Crystal Reports, Excel, and a couple other "DBF Programs" I have on my laptop. No matter what I use to open or access the file the data looks the same. 

I did just come across ReFox from another StackExchange thread that popped up... That allowed me to view the header information. It says "File version: 03 .. FoxBASE+/FoxPro2.x - table". So I think I can safely say that this *IS* some kind of FoxBase/FoxPro file for sure at least.

Comment: What's missing here is the schema. There should be a Type specified for each column somewhere. Most of the xBase tools should be able to show it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ReFox shows the Part Number column type as C(30) and Price as C(10). What do I do with this information now though? Also, would the schema be the parts.cdx file?

Comment: I think the CDX is an index file. C(30) is probably a CHAR(30). Do post a complete schem so we can compare with the other columns.

Comment: C(30) and C(10) proably means someone decided to use ther own (binary) type and plug it into a CHAR (or BYTE) column.

Comment: Looks like the fields use some kind of non-ASCII 8-bit encoding. The 9s are padding, and i notice the price field (at least) always has the `G` in the same relative position (third from the end), which suggests it represents the decimal point, and `I`-`R` are digits (but not necessarily as 0-9).

Comment: Try to find out what should be in the Price and PartNo columns, then you may have chance or reverse engineering it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What do you mean by "post a complete schema"? Where do I find the schema/what is it supposed to look like? I did some digging, tried to install an old version of FoxBase to open the dbf. Didn't work though because FoxBase is 8bit and I'm not using a computer from the stone ages. So yeah, if this is a FoxBase DBF then 8 bit encoding makes sense in that case, right?

Comment: It does seem if you subtract 25 from the code for each character in the price column, you end up with what looks passingly like a price. Even the 9s (ascii 57) become spaces (ascii 32).

Comment: A schama is the list of columsn with their Type and Length and maybe other specifications.

Comment: Okay. So... I have something. Part Number (dbf) KIKLQNFO9999999999999999999999 equals Part Number (readable) 202385-6. The Price (dbf) JKJKGNI999 equals Price (readable) 1212.50.

Comment: Also, the schema type for all fields is C(x) where x is a number ranging from 2 up to 35. There is one D(8) which is a date field.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the schema (I think?) to the original post. What do you mean by subtract 25 from the code? how?

Comment: Computers don't represent characters directly, but as numbers in a given encoding. The character `I`, for example, is represented in ASCII by the number 73. 73 - 25 = 48. And 48 just happens to be the ASCII code for the character `0`. Do that for each character, and you seem to end up with something readable. It's pretty easy to do, but the code to do it depends on what programming language you use.

Comment: Holy Moly. That's crazy. It's working out correctly. I mean I've only done a few.. but yeah. Find the letter in the ASCII table to assign it's value, deduct 25 from the value, find the new ASCII character associated... put it all together... Part and Price are both correct. I'm amazed. How in the everloving eff did you figure that out !? Also... now what do I do with this info? lol I guess do an index match in Excel to read it out or something. I'm no programmer unfortunately.

Comment: How? An understanding of how computers do text + a knack for recognizing patterns + a bit of experience messing with others' hare-brained "encryption" schemes. :)

Comment: As for what to do from here...personally, i'd whip up a VBA function to do the decoding in Excel. That's me, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 0x03 in header's first byte it is a Foxbase table. As cHao already pointed out, the author decided to create those columns with some byte shifting of each character (I wouldn't call that encryption though, too easy to solve for any programmer - or non-programmer with some pattern discovery).

Now the question is how you can utilize that data without damaging the original. One idea is to take a copy, alter the data in it and use that copy instead. Doing that with some computer language is easy when you are a programmer, but you are saying you are not. Then comes the question, which language code you could simply get and compile on your computer.

Well I wanted to play with this as a skill testing for myself and came up with some C# code. It was quite easy to write, and compile on any windows machine (so I thought, I had been doing that since years ago). I was mistaken, I don't know why nor have a will to investigate, but the executable created using command line compiler (any windows have it already) is blocked by my antivirus! I signed it but nothing changed. I gave up very quickly.

Luckily there was another choice which I think is better anyways. Go < g > write and compile with Go - the fantastic language from Google. If you want to spare your 10-15 mins at most to it, I will give you the code and how to compile it into an exe on your computer. First here is the code itself:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "os"
    "io"
    "time"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-adodb"
)


func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        log.Fatal("You need to supply an input filename.")
    }
    source := os.Args[1]
    if _, err := os.Stat(source); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("File [%s] doesn't exist.", source))
    }

    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Converting [%s]...", source))
    saveAs := GetSaveAsName(source)
    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Started conversion on copy [%s]", saveAs))

    ConvertData(saveAs)
    log.Println("Conversion complete.")
}

func ConvertData(filename string) {
    srcBytes := make([]byte, 127-32-1)
    dstBytes := make([]byte, 127-32-1)

    for i := 32; i < 34;i++ {
        srcBytes[i-32]=byte(i+25)
        dstBytes[i-32]=byte(i)
    }
    for i := 35; i < 127; i++ {
        srcBytes[i-33] = byte(i+25)
        dstBytes[i-33] = byte(i)
    }
    src := string(srcBytes) + string(byte('"')+25)
    dst := string(dstBytes)

    dbPath, dbName := filepath.Split(filename)
    db, err := sqlx.Open("adodb", `Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=` + dbPath)
    e(err)
    defer db.Close()

    stmt := fmt.Sprintf(`update ('%s') set 
            p_part_num = chrtran(p_part_num, "%s", "%s"+'"'),
            p_price    = chrtran(p_price,    "%s", "%s"+'"')`,
        dbName, src, dst, src, dst)


    _, err = db.Exec(stmt)
    e(err)
}

func GetSaveAsName(source string) string {
    fp, err := filepath.Abs(source)
    e(err)
    dir, fn := filepath.Split(fp)

    targetFileName := filepath.Join(dir,
        fmt.Sprintf("%s_copy%d.dbf",
            strings.Replace(strings.ToLower(fn), ".dbf", "", 1),
            time.Now().Unix()))
    e(err)

    in, err := os.Open(source)
    e(err)
    defer in.Close()

    out, err := os.Create(targetFileName)
    e(err)
    defer out.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(out, in)
    e(err)
    err = out.Close()
    e(err)
    return targetFileName
}

func e(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

And here are the steps to create an executable out of it (and have Go as a language on your computer for other needs:)

- Download [Go language](http://golang.org) from Google and install it. Its installer is simple to use and finish in a few seconds.
- Open a command prompt. Type:

  Go version [enter]

-You should see installed Go's version (as of now 1.10).

-Type

```
Go env [enter]
```

and check GOPATH , it points the base folder for your go projects. Go to that folder and create 4 folders named:

bin, pkg, src and vendor

By default GOPATH is "Go" under your home folder, looks like this:

c:\users\myUserName\Go

after creating folders you would have:

```
c:\users\myUserName\Go
c:\users\myUserName\Go\bin
c:\users\myUserName\Go\pkg
c:\users\myUserName\Go\src
c:\users\myUserName\Go\vendor
```

using any text editor (Notepad.exe for example) copy & paste and save the code as say "MyCustomConverter.go" into src folder.

Code has 2 external libraries that you need to get. Change directory to your GOPATH (not really necessary but my habit at least) and get those libraries typing:

```
cd %GOPATH%
go get -v github.com/jmoiron/sqlx
go get -v github.com/mattn/go-adodb
```

You are ready to compile your code.

```
cd src
set GOARCH=386
go build MyCustomConverter.go
```

This would create MyCustomConverter.exe that you can use for conversion.

> set GOARCH=386 is needed in this special case, because VFP OLEDB driver is 32 bits driver.

Oh I forgot to tell, it uses VFPOLEDB driver, which you can [download from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839) and install.

You would use the executable like this:

MyCustomConverter.exe "c:\My Folder\parts.dbf"

and it would create a modified version of that named as:

"c:\My Folder\parts_copyXXXXXXXXXX.dbf"

where XXXXXXXXXXX would be a timestamp value (so whenever you run you create another copy, it doesn't overwrite on to one that may exist).

Instead of going to command prompt everytime and typing the fullpath of your parts table, you could copy the MyCustomConverter.exe file on to desktop and drag & drop your parts.dbf on to that exe from windows explorer.

(It was a nice exercise for my Go coding - there would be critics such as why I didn't use parameters but I really had good reasons, driver and the Go library support namely:)

Comment: Last night as I was closing my eyes to go to sleep I saw a StackExg email come through. I briefly looked through your post and fell asleep happily. I spent THE ENTIRE DAY yesterday trying to work something out. I realized Excel was only showing a portion of the data (row limits, ugh). I opened it in Crystal and saw about 8 million more rows of data. I could have probably hobbled something together in Excel, but Crystal would likely need UDFs and I was lost. Discouraged. Frustrated. This post is like a miracle. I'm going to dig in and give it a shot. I'll let you know how it goes. THANK YOU!

Comment: It's running! I have no idea how long it will take but it's going. Your instructions made it SUPER easy. The only hiccups I ran into were easy enough to figure out. For some reason Go didn't put a folder in the default spot so I made one, NBD. Next, trying to do the "go get" commands failed. I had to install git and then it went smooth. Again, still waiting for the exe to finish up it's job... but I'm optimistic. I just want to say Thank You!!! at least one more time. Keep your fingers crossed this exe doesn't choke on 9 million rows now! ;)

Comment: It. Worked. I am so happy I had to get up and high five my accounting girlfriends. They don't really understand but they shared my happiness vicariously anyway. You have saved me, literally, countless hours of work trying to wrap my head around this and then hoping to god I could actually execute a fix. A miracle... Cetin Basoz you are truly a miracle. Thank you a million times.

Comment: I am really delighted :) Taking it long was expected since the filesize was almost at limits for Foxpro (32 bit limit of 2 Gig). I would warn you about Excel and few more but I didn't have time then nor do have now :( If you can add some information about your environment (any database, programming language etc) actually I was even thinking about some code that could do this 8-10x faster (just in theory now), possibly I might toy with such a code later this week and post if you follow the thread in patience :)

Comment: And one question, you really don't have a need that to be DBF, do you.

Comment: It took a little while... but not like an unreasonable amount of time. And I guess I dont really need the file to be a dbf? Though I'm not sure what the alternative is. I also don't what to tell you about my environment either. The database that I'm comparing the dbf data to resides in a Firebird db on our server. I've dabbled with trying to learn Python. Not sure if any of that helps... I'll definitely keep an eye on this topic for anything you're willing to throw my way! :)

Comment: Saying environment that is what I meant - Python and Firebird database :) An alternative to DBF would be something like an SQLite data, postgreSQL, SQL server, Firebird ... I don't use Firebird, but the beauty of Go's "database\sql" library is that it is neutral to backend. I could write for say postgreSQL and all you need would be to change the connection string. I am not promising but there is a possibility I would do this at weekend (just check on Monday:)

Comment: I have MySQL installed on my system as well. Forgot what I was trying to do with it but it's on here. That neutral backend thing seems pretty neat. Like I said, I definitely look forward to whatever, if anything, you throw my way.

Answer (score 0):

> I THINK this file was created in some version of FoxPro

While the DBF Data Tables were CREATED by Foxpro, they are POPULATED by an APPLICATION which may or may not have been written in Foxpro.

And yes, you do not need to worry about the CDX files unless you want to organize (sequence) the data by one of its Indexes or to establish Relationships between multiple Data Tables for processing purposes.   However unless you were to do that using Foxpro/Visual Foxpro itself, it wouldn't be of use to you anyway.

From the comments that you have already received, it looks as though the developers of the APPLICATION that writes the field values into the DBF Data Tables might have encrypted the data.  And it also seems like you may have found how to decrypt it using the suggestions above.

> I'm no programmer unfortunately

If that is the case then I'd suggest that you **STOP RIGHT NOW** before you introduce more problems than you want.  Blindly 'mucking' around with the data might just make things worse.

If this project is **BUSINESS CRITICAL** then you should hire a software consultant familiar with Foxpro/Visual Foxpro to get the work done - after which you can do whatever you want.  Remember that if something is **BUSINESS CRITICAL** then it is worth spending the $$$$

Good Luck